# using Ext.form.updateRecord() to upload file

Tags: forms, file-upload, extjs, extjs4

ExtJS 4.1.

Let's imagine we have some form:

```
Ext.define('App.view.editform', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Basic',
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [
        {
            fieldLabel: 'Title',
            name: 'title',
            allowBlank: false,
        }, {
            xtype: 'textarea',
            fieldLabel: 'Text',
            name: 'text',
            height: 160,
        }, {
            xtype: 'filefield',
            fieldLabel: 'Image',
            name: 'image',
        }, {
            xtype: 'hidden',
            name: 'id',
        }, 
    ],

});
```

and a Store:

```
    Ext.define('App.store.Store', {

    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: new Ext.data.Model({
        fields: [
            {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'title', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'text', type: 'string'},
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/someurl',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'results'
            },
        },
    }),
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,

});
```

To modify `Records` in `Store` we can use `loadRecord();` method on our form and `updateRecord();` method to submit our changes to `Store` (then to server). But at server every `Record` has image associated with it.

`updateRecord();` method only submit text fields to `Store`. `Model` can't contain `binary` type field.

So is there a way to upload an image using forms `updateRecord();` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Gotta have special handler for this on the server side.